# Why am I getting a type value mismatch?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a vector of iterators in my C++ application:

```
std::vector<std::list<std::shared_ptr<SelfDefinedType>>::iterator> edge_iters;
```

`SelfDefinedType` is a class I declared somewhere above this snippet.

I must admit this organization is a bit complicated, but there is a hierarchical structure to the templating.

I am getting the following compile-time error compiling with C++11.

```
App.hpp:563:48: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template 
parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
```

What does this mean? It seems to be treating `std::list<std::shared_ptr<SelfDefinedType>>::iterator` as a value instead of a type. Why?

I tried to add spaces to the beginning and end brackets to no avail. I also tried to use typedef to suppress compilation errors, which didn't work.

Comment: Forget to include a header? (How is your code different from [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2YsIz3$0)). Usually this error is when you forget `typename`, but I can't see the code. Also, please show the entire error.

Comment: A suggestion: be careful with invalidated iterators.

Comment: I've included `<list>`, `<memory>`, and `<vector>`. That should suffice, right?

Comment: What is line 563 in App.hpp?

Comment: "Why?"  My best guess is a missing `typename` somewhere, but you really have to show the code that's causing this error for anyone to tell you **why** it's causing an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify that `std::list<std::shared_ptr<SelfDefinedType>>::iterator` is a type.

Here `iterator` is nested inside `std::list<std::shared_ptr<SelfDefinedType>>` and *SelfDefinedType* is a template parameter.

The parser assumes *iterator* is not a type, unless you tell it explicitly with *typename*.

To solve the error (note the **typename**):

```
std::vector<typename std::list<std::shared_ptr<SelfDefinedType>>::iterator> edge_iters;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the issue but this can be understood as operator>> by your compiler.

Try 
    std::vector< std::list< std::shared_ptr< SelfDefinedType **> >**::iterator > edge_iters;